# <analytics:reportChart> tag cannot be used inside tab views

Tags: apex, visualforce, tabpanel, analytics-reportchart

I have a Custom Vf page which calls a custom component carrying:

Cannot display the data in tabs.

Here is the vf page and component:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0">

    <apex:tabPanel switchType="server">

        <apex:tab label="testing Differences" labelWidth="300" id="tab2"><c:Component1 /></apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Component

```
<apex:component >
 <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Op0000000Iqrst></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:component>
```

The tab does not displays any data .

As checked in the developer forums:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000fzqoIAA

and

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T45IAAS

not sure, if  can be used with a tab.

Please assist. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a Known Issue that seems much more likely to be your issue:

> #### [Spring '15 - `<analytics:reportChart>` tag causes a Javascript error if the component is enclosed within an  tag](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XwOAAU)
>
> **Summary**
>   In Spring '15, a Javascript error is thrown as a result of an  tag being enclosed within an  tag on the same Visualforce page.
>
> **Repro**
>   To reproduce, create a simple Visualforce page as follows:
>
> ```
> <apex:page id="Page" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" > 
>     <apex:tabPanel > 
>         <apex:tab label="Tab1" name="Tab1"> 
>             <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O############"/> 
>         </apex:tab> 
>     </apex:tabPanel> 
> </apex:page>
> ```
>
> When you access the page, you will observe the following Javascript error in the browser console:
>
> > Error while running $A.run() : object is not a function
>
> **Workaround**
>   To workaround this issue you create a new Visualforce new page containing the `<analytics:reportChart>` tag and embed the page inside an `<apex:tab>` tag using an iframe as follows:
>
> Visualforce Page with embedded iframe:
>
> ```
> <apex:page id="Page" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" > 
>     <apex:tabPanel> 
>         <apex:tab label="Tab1" name="Tab1"> 
>             <apex:iframe src="/apex/iframepage"/> 
>         </apex:tab> 
>     </apex:tabPanel> 
> </apex:page>
> ```
>
> Visualforce Page containing  tag to be embedded:
>
> ```
> <apex:page id="Page" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" > 
>     <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O############" /> 
> </apex:page>
> ```

Notice that this Known Issue is currently not fixed in any org, unlike the Known Issue you posted which is fixed in all orgs.